# Control when we receive visual notifications in chat

Tags: feature-request, chat, notifications

I regularly "idle" in chat, by which I mean I'll be connected to all my favourite rooms, with a single tab open pointing to one of them, while doing other things - in case anyone needs me, or an important conversation pops up.

Now, while I'm at work I have no sound available, so if someone hits me with an `@` I usually won't realise until I decide to check on chat to see if anything has happened (unless they've conveniently picked the room I've left visible).

At the moment, users can configure sound notifications to one of a few different states, and these notifications can work cross-room. But *visual* notifications (eg, the star / highlight in the tab's title / pinned tab) are fixed to only notify for changes in the local room.

I'm wondering if we could have the option to configure the visual notifications in a manner similar to how we can configure the sound notifications?

Personally, I'm most interested in receiving a visual notification when I'm `@`ed in another room, but I ideally see this as being another spectrum of options, so that everyone can make it work for their own needs.

Comment: What browser do you use?

Comment: @Rebecca Usually FF4, with my single chat tab pinned.

Comment: [Related request concerning audio rather than visual notifications](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280352/adjust-notification-settings-per-chat-room)